# Querying Get-ADuser where employeeID contains letters

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In part of my script I am trying to query AD Searching by employee number. This works fine for 90% of the employees. however in my organization we have a few special employees where the employee number contains letters thus breaking my powershell command.

here are 2 examples

```
   Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq 12345" -Properties SAMAccountName 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq ABC1234567" -Properties SAMAccountName
```

The first option works fine but the second one fails.

> Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'EmployeeID -eq ABC1234567' Error
>   Message: 'syntax error' at position: '16'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq ABC1234567" -Properties SAMAccou ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Micr
>   osoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work! :)

Answer (score 2):

12345 is treated as an integer, so the filter query doesn't fail.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq 12345" -Properties SAMAccountName
```

Adding **ABC**1234567 to the filter makes the filter a string, the string needs to be wrapped in quotes. Try the command below...

```
 Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq 'ABC1234567'" -Properties SAMAccountName
```

Comment: ok so that works when i run the line in powershell but updating my code it still fails. I probably should have included the line of code im using in the first place...

targetUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($txtEmpNum.Text.ToString())" -Properties SAMAccountName

Comment: Try adding quotes like this... '$($txtEmpNum.Text.ToString())'

Comment: I swear i tried that and it didn't work but evidently I didn't because its working now Thank You!

Comment: Anytime, i'm happy to help.